# UIViewController and required init?(coder: )

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

Xcode keeps give me some runtime error like "fatal error: init(coder:) has not been implemented: file/.../myproject.swift"

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var boardView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var movesLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var timeLabel: UILabel!

    let BOARD_SIZE: Int = 10
    var board: Board 
    var squareButtons: [SquareButton] = []

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.board = Board(size: BOARD_SIZE)
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Since we must implement a required init?(coder:) in subclass so, I try to initialize board in required init at the same time. Clearly it's not working. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove

```
fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
```

line from `required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` initialiser. Your error is thrown by this line. This line is not needed.

XCode adds this line when you create `init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` method to remind developer to implement this method or to never call it. If developer will forget to implement it but will try to instantiate a class from archive or Storyboard he will receive an assert and will be able to find a bug easily.

Comment: thanks, it works. 
Is this line meant to be there? Or are there some kind of errors that we just choose to ignore it?